# Los iconos de Fontawesome no se ven, lo que se ven son figuras irregulares

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-mix

Estoy llevando a cabo un proyecto con laravel-mix, pero los iconos que guarda la galeria fontawesome no se estan mostrando, ya he compilado varias veces con npm run dev y con npm run watch supuestamente deberia cargarse la libreria, pero hasta ahora no se muestran las figuras, solo se ven figuras irregulares, cuando inspecciono la pagina no tengo ningun error, pero me sigue sin salir los iconos, me gustaria que me den una manito con este problema

[image: Este es el codigo de Webpack]

[image: Asi se ven los iconos, con formas irreulares]

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste con eliminar la cache del navegador?

Comment: ya elimine todo el cache del navegador, pero sigue con lo mismo, que mas puedo hacer?